# Comparing objects of an array with each other

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a Powershell array that looks like this:

```
TSMServer Cluster       VM       
--------- -------       --       
HTS01     APP-P02       Server9839
HTS01     APP-P13       Server3221
HTS01     APP-P13       Server3230
HTS05     APP-P12       Server3182
HTS05     APP-P12       Server9829
GTS05     APP-P06       Server0057
GTS05     APP-P06       Server0421
GTS05     APP-P06       Server2426
GTS05     APP-P06       Server0286
GTS05     APP-P06       Server0302
GTS05     APP-P07       Server0312
GTS05     APP-P12       Server2845
GTS05     APP-P12       Server3135
HTS01     APP-P10       Server1052
HTS05     APP-P12       Server3155
HTS05     APP-P12       Server3185
HTS05     APP-P12       Server9830
...
```

I need to find all VMs having the same values for both TSMserver and Cluster.

I need a command to retrieve (e.g.) these 2 VMs because they share the same first value.

```
TSMServer Cluster       VM       
--------- -------       --   
HTS01     APP-P13       Server3221
HTS01     APP-P13       Server3230
```

So actually I need to compare each object in the array to the other ones to find common values for the first 2 properties.

A big THANK YOU in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `Group-Object` cmdlet, like so:
*($servers is the variable that contains the object array here)*

```
$servers | Group-Object -Property TSMServer, Cluster | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object {
   $_.Group | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

For the given example array of objects, running the above will result in:

```
TSMServer Cluster VM        
--------- ------- --        
HTS01     APP-P13 Server3221
HTS01     APP-P13 Server3230



TSMServer Cluster VM        
--------- ------- --        
HTS05     APP-P12 Server3182
HTS05     APP-P12 Server9829
HTS05     APP-P12 Server3155
HTS05     APP-P12 Server3185
HTS05     APP-P12 Server9830



TSMServer Cluster VM        
--------- ------- --        
GTS05     APP-P06 Server0057
GTS05     APP-P06 Server0421
GTS05     APP-P06 Server2426
GTS05     APP-P06 Server0286
GTS05     APP-P06 Server0302



TSMServer Cluster VM        
--------- ------- --        
GTS05     APP-P12 Server2845
GTS05     APP-P12 Server3135
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group-Object

```
$Servers = @"
TSMServer,Cluster,VM,
HTS01,APP-P02,Server9839
HTS01,APP-P13,Server3221
HTS01,APP-P13,Server3230
HTS05,APP-P12,Server3182
HTS05,APP-P12,Server9829
GTS05,APP-P06,Server0057
GTS05,APP-P06,Server0421
GTS05,APP-P06,Server2426
GTS05,APP-P06,Server0286
GTS05,APP-P06,Server0302
GTS05,APP-P07,Server0312
GTS05,APP-P12,Server2845
GTS05,APP-P12,Server3135
HTS01,APP-P10,Server1052
HTS05,APP-P12,Server3155
HTS05,APP-P12,Server3185
HTS05,APP-P12,Server9830
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv 

$Servers | Sort-Object TSMServer,Cluster | Group-Object TSMServer,Cluster|
    ForEach-Object {
        $TSMServer,$Cluster = $_.Name -split ', '
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TSMServer = $TSMServer
            Cluster   = $Cluster
            VMs       =($_.Group.VM | Sort-Object) -Join ','
        }
    }
```

Sample output:

```
TSMServer Cluster VMs
--------- ------- ---
GTS05     APP-P06 Server0057,Server0286,Server0302,Server0421,Server2426
GTS05     APP-P07 Server0312
GTS05     APP-P12 Server2845,Server3135
HTS01     APP-P02 Server9839
HTS01     APP-P10 Server1052
HTS01     APP-P13 Server3221,Server3230
HTS05     APP-P12 Server3155,Server3182,Server3185,Server9829,Server9830
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you so much!